# Is there a command line interpreter for Free Pascal?

Tags: interpreter, pascal, freepascal, shebang, fpc

E.g., one I could use by adding a shebang to my Pascal files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fpi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's instantfpc at fpc's svn trunk:
http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/utils/instantfpc/

Here's the README:

```
instantfpc
==========

This tool allows to execute pascal programs as unix scripts.
A unix script starts with a shebang #! and the program to execute. For example

#!/usr/bin/env instantfpc
begin
  writeln('It works');
end.

If you save the above file as test.pas and set the execute permission
(chmod a+x) you can execute the script simply with
./test.pas


Installation
============

1. Compile instantfpc.lpi using lazarus, lazbuild or via "fpc instantfpc.lpr"
2. Put the executable "instantfpc" in PATH, for example into
   /usr/bin/instantfpc or ~/bin/instantfpc.

That's all.
Now you can execute pascal programs as scripts.
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, `fpc` can't compile code with shebangs, but I look forward to a future version that treats them as comments.

Comment: Yes. instantfpc removes the shebang before compiling it (procedure CommentShebang in instantfptools.pas).

Comment: That's only a workaround--fpc itself can't handle shebangs, so you have to decide for every .PAS file whether you want to run it as a script or compile it.

Comment: Yes, that's true. As a short time solution guess one can write a wrapper around fpc and removes shebangs.